# Nginx configuration to serve a dynamic files within a root folder

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a mern stack application with the following structure

```
.app/
  --client folder
-server.js
-storage folder
```

The application works just fine in local, though when i have deployed to amazone (ec2) and configured pm2 and nginx everything works fine but the only issue that images saved in my storage folder do not seems to be served.
Static images in the build folder are displayed normaly but when the user uplaods his profile image for example which saved in the storage, the image gets saved but not displayed.

My nginx config are very common:

```
root /path/tp/build;

location / {
   try_files $uri /index.html;
}

location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
 //other default configs;
}
```

I was trying to play with config to make it works but wasn't successfull.
I also added a location in the nginx config for the storage folder

```
location /storage/ {
   root /path/to/storage/;
   try_files $uri /;
}
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: What is the URI and the pathname of the file involved? See [how `root` works](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root).

Comment: Sounds like a linux permission issue

Comment: Thanks guys, but i have fixed it, the issue was the back slash, after a couple of hours making changes on the config it woked fine.